# MudBlazor Server File Upload not working even not exist

Tags: c#, mudblazor

I am using MudBlazor frame work, following the instruction on its official site to build an File Upload box in a MudBlazor server side template ([https://mudblazor.com/components/fileupload#api](File Upload)). When I copy and past the sample code from the example, it show as the MudFileUpload Component is not exist, and same as that buttonTemplate component. Wondering, can some one help me here to make it work? Thanks ahead.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cp7aa.png)

Can anyone please help, to make it work, maybe I missing something here.

Comment: Did you look at the error list window? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/error-list-window?view=vs-2022 - it should tell you what the error is

Comment: Check your mudblazor nuget version and _imports.razor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my MudBlazor package to 6.7.0 version in dependency, the issue fixed.

Comment: This is more a comment on the question than a separate answer